# Javascript if/else question

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wanna open a div and close it with this function but it doesnt work where is the wrong part i couldnt fix it, can anyone help me ?

```
function Element(id)
{    
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block')
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly by clicking the Format Code button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you ! This one worked.! but I changed the code inside of if. Because it says if you find block which should be none.

```
function Element(id) { 
    if( document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    } else { 
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` statement assigns the property instead of comparing it.
Change `=` to `===`.

Comment: Just to clarify @SLaks' answer, `=` is an assignment operator (e.g. `foo = "bar"`). `==` and `===` are comparison operators (e.g. `if ( foo == "bar"`).

Comment: Specifically, the = in the if(...) should be changed, but the others shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you rewrite it with the ternary operator, its much more readable and maintainable:

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.style.display = element.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
```

Comment: Move the `?` and the `:` up a line or you could be a victim of semicolon insertion.

Comment: @indieinvader: I don't think semicolon insertion would have occured in his first version, not even if he did put a return before the statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Element(id) { 
        if( document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block') {
             document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
       } else { document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `else` or a ternary operator as your first condition has no effect. So this will suffice...

```
if(document.getElementById(id).style.display != 'block')
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Ah, I see your own answer has the action reversed so this no longer applies.